# How to send coupon code to user when register account in opencart

Tags: opencart, coupon

How can I email a coupon code to new customers when they register on the Opencart website?

```
i have set 
Customer Login=yes
```

on the coupon section. When customer register it doesn't contain any coupon code.

Comment: You don't have coupon, but still when a user register you want to create a new coupon and send it to him, right? Did you complete sending coupon code to user if a coupon is already available?

Comment: i have create coupon code on admin section. when i use coupon code on checkout it working fine. i need to send that coupon code to every user who register on the site through email. better if i can send coupon code on register email which is received by user

Comment: If you have a coupon, you can get it by mysql query, right? You know `addCustomer` model function and the email code in it. Using the mysql query, you can simply get coupon code and append it to the email message.

Comment: i am searching for any built in function for that. if not built in function then i'll try your idea.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way possible to do this would be add the coupon code to the registration mail language files.  Look at **catalog/language/english/mail/customer.php** and edit the text of one of the variables.  For example:

```
$_['text_thanks'] = 'Please use coupon code XXXXXX at checkout on your first order. Thanks,';
```

You could also add a new variable, and update the controller and template if you want more control over how and where it's displayed, but using one of the existing variables would be much easier in my opinion.